# How to connect to a WiFi from command line under Ubuntu without .conf file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, bash, wpa-supplicant

I can connect to my WiFi out of the shell by doing:

```
nano wireless-wpa.conf
```

typing:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={
ssid="my_router_id" 
scan_ssid=1
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
psk="1234567890"
}
```

and doing:

```
ifconfig eth1 down
iwconfig eth1 mode Managed
ifconfig eth1 up
killall wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -B -Dwext -i eth1 -c ./wireless-wpa.conf -dd
dhclient eth1
```

Pretty complicated.. Is there a possibility to connect to a WiFI via shell without the need of a **wireless-wpa.conf**?

Comment: Would having a script that wrote the .conf on the fly and established the network connection suffice?

Comment: Actually I was looking for a complete different solution, because I could write a bash script myself.

Answer (score 15):

You can control a running wpa_supplicant using it's control interface, which you already specify in your .conf file. While this still needs a .conf file, you don't have to put any wireless networks in it, and don't have to change it. You can then configure it with `wpa_cli`.

`wpa_cli` may need to be told which wpa_supplicant instance and interface to configure:

```
wpa_cli -p /var/run/wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 command ...
```

For clarity, I'll use just `wpa_cli` here. Basically, you need to create a network, set its variables, and enable it:

```
# wpa_cli add_network
4                                          <--- note the network ID!
# wpa_cli set_network 4 ssid '"Your SSID"'
OK
# wpa_cli set_network 4 scan_ssid 1
OK
# wpa_cli set_network 4 key_mgmt WPA-PSK
OK
# wpa_cli set_network 4 psk '"1234567890"' <--- note the single quotes around
OK
# wpa_cli enable_network 4
OK
```

Comment: you might want to start with wpa_cli scan followed by wpa_cli scan_results to gather what SSID's are available

Comment: The single quotes around the strings helped me, but what do you do when there is a single quote in the SSID? It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The single quotes trick helped me. How can I used a variable like `psk=$3` instead?

Answer (score 0):

You want a cli command that manages your wpa_suplicant-config?
Have you tried `ifup`, `ifdown` and `ifcfg`? They handle connection scripts and work for wifi too but may need some tinkering with.